# How do I determine if current device does have a P3 capable display?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, cgcolor

Is there a way to conditionally select a Standard RGB color or a P3 color if the device supports it?

I thought about something like the following for iOS versions:

```swift
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UITraitCollection` has a `displayGamut` property, which is an [`enum UIDisplayGamut`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidisplaygamut)

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
public enum UIDisplayGamut : Int {
    case unspecified // UIKit will not set this anymore, instead a sensible default is chosen based on the device capabilities and settings always
    case SRGB
    case P3
}
```

You can query the “main screen”

```
let hasP3Display = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.displayGamut == .P3
```

or the display of a specific view (which can be different if an external monitor is used)

```
let hasP3Display = view.traitCollection.displayGamut == .P3
```

Comment: Former should be used only if you're 100% sure users won't use any external screens with your app. Or if you don't care how it would look on external monitor.